# How to trigger something if all objects return false

Tags: java, oop

There is probably a similar question out like this but I don't know the exact words of what I am looking for.

I have a class named `Command`

```java
package loopturn.loanbot.main;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Command extends ListenerAdapter implements CommandInterface {

    private String command;
    private CommandExecutor executor;

    public Command(String command, CommandExecutor executor) {
        this.command = command;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public Boolean onCommand() {
        return null;
    }

    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] messageSplitBySpace = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");

        if(messageSplitBySpace[0].startsWith("!")) {
            if(messageSplitBySpace[0].equalsIgnoreCase("!" + command)) {
                executor.onCall(event);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And I create a new command for every command. Seems simple, right. Well how would I make it so when a command is ran but doesn't exist (A command starts by sending a message that starts with a `'!'`) it tells them it doesn't exist.

I had an idea of creating another class that took in the command and then called command when it was said in chat, but it doesn't feel like its the right solution. I wanted to see if anyone could think of a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a lookup table and return a default if/when the command is not found.

```
execute( String command ) { 
    Command c = map.get(command)
    if (c = null) {
       c = new EmptyCommand()
    }
    c.run();
}
```

That way if the command is found, you execute it, and if it's not, you execute an `EmptyCommand` that does nothing (or in your case, displays the "Invalid command" message to the user or something similar).

Comment: The goal isn't to do nothing; *"when a command is ran but doesn't exist ... it tells them it doesn't exist."*

Answer (score 0):

I will advice to create an independent factory for discovering a command based on the `event.getMessage()`. When the event is containing "!" this factory would generate a special command say "NaNCommand". On this command you can handle all scenarios of calling a command which doesn't exist.

```
Command c = CommandFactory.discover(event)
c.execute()
```

```
public class CommandFactory{

public static discover(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){

String[] messageSplitBySpace = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");

        if(messageSplitBySpace[0].startsWith("!")) {
         // send NaNCommand
        }
        else{
         //Check event and pass a valid command
        }
}
}
```